# Unusual Inconsistencies in Gibbs Free Energy Values at Specific Temperatures in Thermodynamic Simulation

Tags: thermodynamics, metal

I was using FactSageEdu software to simulate a metal with a composition of 67% titanium (Ti) and 33% aluminum (Al). During the simulation, I encountered an inconsistency in the calculated Gibbs free energy values (Gibbs free energy or G) at specific temperatures within the range of 933.45°C to 1166°C. These inconsistencies appear in the data as follows:

At 933.45°C, the Gibbs free energy was calculated as -3956630.1 J.
At 1166°C, the Gibbs free energy was calculated as -5565831.4 J.
These unexpected fluctuations in Gibbs free energy values within this temperature range are greater than typical variations and can have significant implications for our understanding of the thermodynamic properties and behavior of the material. Addressing and resolving this inconsistency is crucial for ensuring the accuracy and reliability of the simulation results and advancing our understanding of the system being studied.

I am seeking assistance and insights to understand the possible sources of this inconsistency and to identify potential solutions or adjustments in the simulation process to obtain more accurate Gibbs free energy values.[image]

Comment: Well, the first thing to check is what formula(s) you used and compare to standard databases such as Dinsdale’s paper.

Comment: 7 valid digits seem quite funny.

Comment: No, the issue does not appear to be solely related to the number of significant digits. I conducted a simulation using a composition of Al 53, Ti 46, and C 1, which adhered to the fundamental principles, and there were no apparent issues. Therefore, it is likely that the inconsistencies observed in the previous simulation are related to data entry or specific conditions associated with the Ti 67 and Al 33 composition.

Comment: I  have not said that significant digits are the reason of the issue. I  have wanted to say that presenting (internal using is OK) 7 significant digits is hardly justified, considering the accuracy of input data and rules of error propagation. // A kind of like presenting illustrative value 1.234567 +- 0.002